# How to use executor service in loop for each iteration?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

```
private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

public void myMethod(){
    int batchSize = 2;
    // calling for 3 pages to test
    for(int i=0;i<3; i++) {
        int[] pageNum = {-1};
        executorService.execute(() -> {
            pageNum[0] = pageNum[0] + 1;
            fetchDataAndPushEvents(pageNum[0], batchSize);  
        }); 
    }
}
private void fetchDataAndPushEvents(int pageNum, int batchSize) {
    log.info("Fetching data for page number: {} and batch size: {}", pageNum, batchSize);
        
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNum, batchSize);
    List<AnswerDto> result = myService.getAllResponse(pageable).getContent();
    long secondTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    log.info("Time taken to fetch data for page number: {} and batch size: {} is :{}", pageNum, batchSize, secondTime-startTime);

    if(!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(result)) {
        log.info("Pushing events for page number: {} and batch size: {}", pageNum, batchSize);
        pushSomeEvent(result);
        log.info("Time taken to push event for page number: {} and batch size: {} is :{}", pageNum, batchSize, System.currentTimeMillis()-secondTime);
        } else {
            // to terminate the process
            return;
        }
    }
```

My aim is to fetch data of batch size 2(say) and for 3(say) batches/pages as mentioned in the above code. I'm trying to give the responsibility for fetching the data and pushing the event for a page to a thread i.e. 1 thread for 1 page. I worked on it and able to write the above logic.

But when I'm trying to run the above code, I'm getting the same 2 response(as the batch size) from the `getAllResponse` repository call for all three iterations. The `pageNum` is not updating. Getting all responses of page 0, hence the same event is getting pushed in all 3 iterations. How should I approach this problem?
PS: I have not much knowledge about executorService.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not increasing the pageNum it will have same value for each iteration.
you have to use separate counter variable for it like below.

```
 int pageNum = 0; 
 for(int i=0, pageCounter=0;i<3; i++,pageCounter++) {
    executorService.execute(() -> {
        fetchDataAndPushEvents(pageNum + pageCounter, batchSize);  
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I totally forgot about it. Also, can you please tell if I use infinite while loop `while(true){}` instead of above finite `for` loop, how should I exit/shutdown the executor service when the `result` list is empty?

Comment: add condition within the while loop with break after successful exist call the shutdown / shutdownnow methods of the executor service.